# How do you know which Azure App Service instance you are accessing?

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

I scaled out like 2 instances of Azure App Service that hosts my web app.

Now, there are 3 instances running the same thing.

I need to know every response returned by every instance.

How do I know which instance I am calling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for the **`WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID`** Environment variable:

> the id representing the VM that the site is running on (If site runs
> on multiple instances, each instance will have a different id).

[Source.](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#website-environment-variables)

Comment: Thanks! This resolves the first question. Now, I am testing them. How do I force my requests to reach the specified instance? I need to test every one of them.

Comment: You can probably achieve this using the ARRAffinity Cookie- this might be a good read: https://blog.paraspatidar.com/web-app-instance-name-and-arr-affinity-mapping-using-function-app-part-1/index.html